# Как защитить авторские права на сайт?

Tags: авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

есть сайт, на котором пользователи могут публиковать фото-аудио-видеозаписи, обмениваться сообщениями и создавать группы
Сайт полностью создавался (фронтенд и бэкенд) одним физическим лицом
Пока что я знаю, что усложнить действия злоумышленников и защитить все части сайта от копирования поможет значок авторского права с появляющемся при клике модальным окном, где описаны права на сайт и запрет копирования исходного кода сайта (части фронтенд), также нужно тоже самое продублировать в пользовательском соглашение
Но наверняка этого мало (в юриспруденции вообще не разбираюсь)
Подскажите пожалуйста, какие пункты следует вносить в пользовательское соглашение на сайте (или куда-либо еще), дабы объявить себя единственным и полноправным владельцем ресурса, предотвратив любое копирование дизайна сайта (любой части его исходных кодов html css js), а также защитить название домена и название сайта?

Comment: Ничего вносить вообще не нужно, все права начинают автоматически действовать ([ГК РФ, ст. 1228, п. 3](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_64629/61d6709b930465436b5adb0943843ed28ff5dd8e/)) и автоматически защищаются ([ГК РФ, ст. 1259, п. 4](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_64629/be05678dc42ddc67aae5be9ba9beebd367fb9a3f/))

Comment: А для защиты названий, наверное, нужно зарегистрировать торговую марку или типа того